# Клавиатурный тренажер не работает

Tags: c#

Выводиться рандомная буква -> печатаете эту букву -> count++, если нет, то count = 0. Но после ввода правильной буквы, count присваивается 0 почему? Вроде бы должно работать.

```
       static void EngTest(){
            Console.Clear();
            char[] eng = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
            Random random = new Random();

            int count = 5;
            int max = 0;
            while (true){
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(count);
                string word = Convert.ToString(eng[random.Next(0, eng.Length)]);
                Console.WriteLine(word);
                if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape){
                    string wordTyped = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (String.Equals(wordTyped, word) == true){
                        count++;
                        if (max <= count){
                            max = count;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Console.WriteLine($"aCount: {count}\nMax wins: {max}");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Ошибка кроется, как мне кажется в этих строках.

```
if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape){
string wordTyped = Console.ReadLine();
    if (String.Equals(wordTyped, word) == true){
    count++;
```

Comment: Источник проблемы как раз не в условиях, исправил заголовок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.ReadKey().Key` съедает ввод, хотите убедиться - сделайте `Console.ReadKey(true).Key`, и просто перестанете видеть первый введенный символ.

А в `wordTyped` у пусто, так как `ReadLine()` успевает считать только `Enter`. Используйте отладку, ставьте точку останова, выполняйте код пошагово. Это лучший способ исправлять такого рода ошибки.

```
static void EngTest()
{
    Console.Clear();
    Random random = new Random();

    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"{count,-10}");
        char expected = (char)('A' + random.Next(26));
        Console.WriteLine(expected);
        
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            break;

        char actual = char.ToUpper(keyInfo.KeyChar);

        if (actual == expected)
        {
            count++;
            if (max < count)
                max = count;
        }
        else
            count = 0;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Count: {count}{Environment.NewLine}Max: {max}");
}
```